# Nonlinear minimum Mean Square Error estimation

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation, mean-square-error

Let say I have the following parameter to estimate:

$$ \theta = \frac{1}{\mu^2 - 1} \ .$$

The observed measurement is $x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$, $\mu^2\neq1$. The mean $\mu$ is unknown. There are two cases I am interested in:

1. The value $\sigma$ is known
2. The value of $\frac{\sigma}{\mu}$ is known

What is a [minimum mean square error (MMSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_mean_square_error) estimator $\hat{\theta}(x) = \text{argmin}_{\theta_0(x)} \mathbb{E}[(\theta_0(x) - \theta)^2] $ for the given function? Will it be unbiased?

(I have asked [the same question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473798/nonlinear-minimum-mean-square-error-estimation)  on Cross Validated 3 days ago.)

Comment: The easiest approach to estimate $\theta$ would be to estimate $\mu$ by maximum likelihood and then use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method

Comment: Can you imagine *any* unbiased estimator, having infinite expectation exactly for $\mu^2=1?$

Comment: @ProfessorVector, please consider $\mu^2\neq1$.